# Getting error while passing value for a phone number using RESTlet in Netsuite

Tags: php, netsuite

In Netsuite, Minimum 7 characters are allowed. I am able to save the phone number +1(313) in Netsuite directly from UI. But if I try to save the same number +1(313) using RESTlet, I get the following error:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => INVALID_FLD_VALUE
            [message] => You have entered an Invalid Field Value +1(313) for the following field: altphone
        )

)
```

My Request data is :

```
Array
(
    [recordtype] => lead
    [id] => xxxxx
    [columnname] => Array
        (
            [0] => altphone
        )

    [columnvalues] => Array
        (
            [0] => +1(313)
        )
)

Working:
 +916(313) [can save directly on netsuite and also RESTlet]
Not working:
 +1(313) [can save directly on netsuite]
+91(313) [can save directly on netsuite]
```

My Restlet script for update :

```
function update_record(datain) {
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord(datain.recordtype, datain.id);
    for ( var i in datain.columnname) {
        record.setFieldValue(datain.columnname[i], datain.columnvalues[i]);
    }
    var results = nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: can you add your RESTlet code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried below code in SuiteScript Debugger and browser console :

```
x = nlapiLoadRecord('lead', RECORD_ID);
x.setFieldValue('altphone', '+1(313)');
nlapiSubmitRecord(x);
```

It fails from code, but, it, succeeds from UI. So, it will fail in RESTlet as well as it is failing in any SuiteScript.